# CSS grid row not moving?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am new to the grid but having issues with the 'grid-row' not working how it should? My 'content' div does not seem to span from where I set the row from and does not go all the way down. If I remove -1 and set it to the last row being 13 it still has a space underneath?!

Also do I need to get a height per section? So does .header and .main need a fixed height?

Here is a CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zdjvmd?editors=1100

```css
.header {
  background-color: pink;
}

.main {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 250px;
}


.grid {
  min-width: 1280px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-row: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.header-logo {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-column: 2 / 8;
}

.header-navigation {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-column: 8 / -1;
  grid-row: 2 / 13;
}

.sidebar{
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 4 / -1;
  grid-row: 4 / -1; /* <-- This is my issue */
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="header-logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="header-navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main class="main">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content here</p>
        <p>Content here</p>
        <p>Content here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: FYI the property is `grid-template-rows` and you have `grid-template-row`. Is that how it is in your code or is that a transcription error?

Comment: Tyler! You're a 100% correct, can't believe I didn't see that, it now works!! Kicking myself for that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're having issues possibly because you're using two separate grids, e.g. they are not aware of each other. Not sure if the following is useful in your scenario, but I personally like to use the `grid-template-areas` property much better than trying to control the grid with `grid-column` or `grid-row`, like that it's easy to have kind of an overview of the layout of the grid. It might seem to be a bit repetitive but the `grid-template-areas` property requires you to specify each column (you can have empty cells by using a `.` instead of the area name!), so as we have 12 columns here it's a bit more typing =)... on the other hand, as you might notice: The required markup is much cleaner and the css as well.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
 "l l n n n n n n n n n n"
 "s s s s m m m m m m m m";
}

.main.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
 "ml ml mr mr mr mr"
 "mb mb mb mb mb mb";
}

.header-logo {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-area: l;
}

.header-navigation {
  background-color: coral;
  grid-area: n;
}

.header-navigation-list {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
  .header-navigation-list a {
    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
  }

.sidebar {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: s;
}

.main {
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: m;
}
.main-right {
  background: teal;
  grid-area: mr;
}
.main-left {
  background: lightseagreen;
  grid-area: ml;
}
.main-bottom {
  background: gold;
  grid-area: mb;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="header-logo">Logo</div>
  <nav class="header-navigation">
    <ul class="header-navigation-list">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <aside class="sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </aside>

  <main class="main grid">
    <div class="main-left">
      <p>Content left here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-right">
      <p>Content right here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main-bottom">
      <p>Content bottom here</p>
    </div>
  </main>
<div>
```

EDIT: Adapted the example to show nested grid and removed max-width width-control addition as it caused confusion =)

Comment: Hi thanks for that! I was looking at grid-template-areas, but a lot of my layouts are crazy with a lot of nesting elements, so not sure if using  grid-template-areas will get messy for complex layouts.

Comment: you're welcome, if the layouts are complex and nested then I would at least avoid having two grids on the same level, e.g. you can nest them within each other by specifying another grid let's say within the header or the content of the "main" grid.

Comment: ah got you, will try that, also I saw you set the max-width: 75%; of the .grid class, a lot of my designs use a full 12fr to span all the way over but i will try what you said,

Comment: Added an example for a nested content grid, hope it helps! The 75% are just there to show how to control the width (so it basically divides 75% of the available viewport into 12 units) , if you remove it, it will span the entire viewport!

Comment: perfect! I see how it works now, Thank you once again and accept your answer as the correct one. My earlier approach was not the right way to use CSS grid.

Comment: Oh it wasn't "wrong" per se, I just find it much more maintainable this way =)